# Intercept GuzzleHTTP Request and Response Bodies

Tags: php, guzzle

I have a need to override the GuzzleHTTP\Client to log the request and response bodies.  I only have ability to change the client in use.  Problem I'm having is these are streams and seems reading the contents (at least for response) breaks the request.

Can you think of another way to intercept request/response bodies via extending the Client?

```
class MyClient extends GuzzleHTTP\Client {

  public function send(RequestInterface $request, array $options = []) {
    // This doesn't affect original request for some reason
    MyLogger::log($request->getBody()->getContents());

    $response = parent::send($request, $options);

    // This breaks the original request call, I think because stream is read only once
    MyLogger::log($response->getBody()->getContents());

    return $response;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix here is to rewind the stream after reading the contents of the response

```
MyLogger::log($response->getBody()->getContents());
$response->getBody()->rewind();
return $response
```

Comment: Another option is to call `$response->getBody()` which will cast the contents of the stream into a string.  A more explicit option would be to call `$response->getBody()->__toString()`

Comment: thx for tip for `$response->getBody()->rewind();` method !

Answer (score 1):

Guzzle's middleware framework provides end users with a natural method to perform specific actions under specific criteria without resorting to extending `GuzzleHttp\Client`

An example of this could be:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\MessageFormatter;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use Monolog\Logger;

$stack = HandlerStack::create();
$stack->push(
    Middleware::log(
        new Logger('Logger'),
        new MessageFormatter('{req_body} - {res_body}')
    )
);

$client = new Client([
   'debug' => true,
   'handler' => $stack, 
]);

$r = $client->get('some_random_uri')->getBody();
```

Documentation is not the best for `GuzzleHttp\Middleware::Log()` or for `GuzzleHttp\MessageFormatter`.  A complete list of options is available within the [MessageFormatter](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/MessageFormatter.php)